# How to call controller method from another controller/file in magento 2

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2

I have controller with following functions,

```
<?php

namespace Custom\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\UpdateData;

class Save 
{

    /**
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute()
    {
       /* ----------
        Code
       */
    }
     /**
     * @return void
     */
    public function getData($param1)
    {
       /* ----------
        Code
       */
    }

}
```

How to call getData from another controller/file in Magento 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well if you want to have access to the function `getData` in the controller, you will need to initiate it using the constructor like in the following example.

```
class CustomClass extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
/**
 * @var \Custom\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\UpdateData\Save
 */
private $_save;

/**
 * CustomClass constructor.
 *
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context               $context
 * @param \Custom\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\UpdateData\Save $save
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Custom\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\UpdateData\Save $save
) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->_save = $save;
}

/**
 * @return void
 */
public function execute()
{
    //example
    $this->_save->getData('order_id');
}
}
```

But why do you want to this?

Comment: I want to access the controller methods instead of duplicating same methods twice in controllers.

Answer (score 1):

Put your getData function in another class and add that class as a dependency to both controllers, instead of having one controller depending on the other.